# Run tcpdump in background

Tags: python, shell, network-programming, wifi

I have a problem , I'm make an experiment, so I'm trying to run python script over double ssh , so I have to capture traffic on every node then I made a function that I can run on each node. But the problem is that I can't run the script in order to start traffic after launched Tcpdump ( the prompt is hang after running tcp dump ). I tried many way to fix these issues but I still have note the best one. I just want a tick to run tcpdump in background and still running other command on the node.

I already tried option "nohup" or putting "&" at the end but I've got syntax error. I'm running this on Mac os.

this is the python script shell in pom.sh :

```py
def function(run-tcpdump):
    local interface="mon0"; shift
    local output="fit"; shift

    local USAGE="Usage; $FUNCNAME interface output [tcpdump extra args]"

  [ -z "$output" ] && { echo $USAGE; return 1; }

    cd
    local command="tcpdump -n -U -w ${output}.pcap -i ${interface} " 
    echo "${interface} traffic tcpdump'ed into $pcap with command:"
    echo "$command"
    $command

    return 0
```

and this is where I call the function in pom.py:

```py
 run_sender = SshJob(
        node=sender,
        commands=[RunScript(auxiliary_script, "run-tcpdump"),
        RunScript(auxiliary_script, "run-sender", packets, size, period)],

        label="run-sender")
```

As you can see I have to run other function called run-sender to start sending packets but when the tcpdump function is launched the remote shell is hangged and I can't run the function "run-sender" anymore.

this is the description below:

Waiting for some interface to run on driver iwlwifi
Using wlan device intel
tcpdump: listening on mon0, link-type IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header), capture size 262144 bytes

NB/ Sorry for my badenglish :)
Thanks you all.